# Overwrite existing value with new value

Tags: go

Look at the following code snippet.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type class struct {
    prop1 string
    prop2 string
}

func main() {

    va1 := &class{"Hello", "Foo"}
    fmt.Println(&va1)
    va1 = &class{"TOO", "Boo"}
    fmt.Println(&va1)

}
```

As a result I've got the same pointed address.

```
0x1215a0c0
0x1215a0c0
```

With &T{} it will allocate new zeroed value address. But why here I've got the same address? Do I just override on second assignment the value?

Comment: Address of address. Please work through the Go tour and Effective Go.

Comment: you're printing a `**class`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement

```
fmt.Println(&va1)
```

prints the address of the variable `va1`, not what `va1` is pointing to. The address of the variable does not change.

Try this program:

```
va1 := &class{"Hello", "Foo"}
fmt.Printf("&va1: %v, pointer: %p, value: %v\n", &va1, va1, va1)

va2 := va1
va1 = &class{"TOO", "Boo"}

fmt.Printf("&va1: %v, pointer: %p, value: %v\n", &va1, va1, va1)
fmt.Printf("&va2: %v, pointer: %p, value: %v\n", &va2, va2, va2)
```

This program prints:

```
&va1: 0x1030e0c0, pointer: 0x10328000, value: &{Hello Foo}
&va1: 0x1030e0c0, pointer: 0x10328050, value: &{TOO Boo}
&va2: 0x1030e0d0, pointer: 0x10328000, value: &{Hello Foo}
```

Note that the address of the variable va1 does not change, but what va1 points to does change. Also, the assignment of a pointer to va1 does not modify the value va1 pointed to.

Comment: To get the address of the variable : `fmt.Printf("%p, %p\n", va1, va2)`